# Is it useful to track files with Git if not about to commit them?

Tags: git

I'm been using Git for the first time on my current project. I've been leaving my modified files as untracked while I work on them, and then I commit them when I'm ready.

This seems to be working fine for me but is there a down side to leaving them untracked before I'm ready to commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downside is that you might lose the files.

The main approach I use is to always work in branches with many commits and then when finally ready to commit to master, it is one commit.

Another approach that can help address both the desire to commit early and often and also the desire to only commit finished work is to use wip (work-in-progress) commits, combined with interactive rebasing.

This way you can do:

```
# work (edit files)
git add and git commit -m"wip"
# work (edit files)
git add and git commit -m"wip"
# work (edit files)
git add and git commit -m"wip"
git rebase -i HEAD # bring up an editor
```

now use squash to combine the three commit together into a commit with a more meaningful description.

Now you have just the one commit, probably annotated, available for direct diff with other commits.

Some notes on interactive rebasing:

- It's not very intuituive at least initially
- you can mess up easily.  Be careful and slow and read all the help carefully
- practice it before you need it on a copy of the *entire) repo.
- consider making a copy of the entire repo (disk space is cheap) the first few times you use it
- it can often be easier to do 1 commit at a time, save and exit and then re-enter.

Note: one time when its good NOT to add the files in any way is when they have personal or private information that will soon be removed.  It is better to NEVER have that information in git or people could go digging for it in the history.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the downside is that Git doesn’t know about them, so it can’t protect you at all. If you add a file to the index using `git add`, then Git will already store that file’s content within its object database. So the content at that time is backed up. If you now lose the file in your working directory for whatever reason, then Git still has that content stored in the index, and you can still commit it. That applies to changes in both tracked as well as untracked files.

In general though, you should try to get used to make your commits smaller and commit more often instead. It’s not a shame to commit things that are “not finished” or “not perfect”. Of course, if you have good control over it, you would always prefer those, but if you can’t it’s fine as well. So instead of waiting with the files until they are “done”, just commit states in between. And if that causes you to end up with a mess, you can still rebase your comments to clean up the history (of course you only rebase if you didn’t push it yet).

Answer (score 0):

depends,

- It is really easy to commit and then later before push you do rebase
- You can also amend last commit instead but that is not what you should do as workflow
- "Not commiting before you are done" is only useful for small parts of features you are working - so you can have meaningful commit messages instead of 100 commits with messages of "Feature X at y% done". Also visual clues of IDE is really helpful here too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best approach is to commit (at least) twice: when you start working and when you stop.

First, it gets much easier to track your changes, especially when there are many files or when time span between commits is more than 1 working day. If you have changes in version control - GIT - then you can ALWAYS see them, compare them with some other version, return to them when needed and check which changes are made. If files are untracked you have no history, only final version.

Secondly, if there is some unexpected situation, e.g. power shortage, and your changes are untracked and files get spoiled, they are totally lost. If there is some unfinished version in GIT you lose only a one day of work or less.

tl;dr: commit every several hours to save work; leaving files untracked is OK for a working day or less.